# How to get the inverse of a ComplexDoubleMatrix using jblas

Tags: java, matrix, eigenvector, eigenvalue

Basically, I would like to calculate the inverse of a matrix which belongs to the ComplexDoubleMatrix class, but I did not find such a function like inverse() or inv(), does any body know how to calculate the inverse of a matrix? Thank you in advance.

My final goal is to create a eigen decomposition of a matrix using jblas.eigen. 
Now my current implementation is by jama library below. To perform similar functions, I need to calculate Vinverse, that is why I want to find an inverse function in jblas.

```
public static SimpleEigenDecomposition SimpleEigenDecomposition(double [][] rates)
 {
     Matrix ratesMatrix = new Matrix(rates);
     EigenvalueDecomposition ed = new EigenvalueDecomposition(ratesMatrix);
     Matrix V = ed.getV();
     Matrix D =ed.getD();
     Matrix Vinverse = V.inverse();
     Matrix resultMatrix = V.times(D).times(V.inverse());
   //check if result and rates are close enough
     SimpleMatrix trueMatrix = new SimpleMatrix(rates);
     SimpleMatrix calculatedMatrix = new SimpleMatrix(resultMatrix.getArray()) ;
     if(EJMLUtils.isClose(trueMatrix, calculatedMatrix, THRESHOLD))
   {
      return new  SimpleEigenDecomposition(V, D, Vinverse);
   }else{
     throw new RuntimeException();
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that there is no inverse operation because that is simply too computationally expensive if done using Cramer's Rule. I initially thought this weird as it could have been implemented using Gauss Jordon elimination. But it is strange that even I could not find one. If anyone finds it in JBLAS please comment below.

One alternative that I can suggest is using **pinv()**. It uses the least square method and is present in **org.jblas.Solve** as a static function.

```
import org.jblas.Solve

public static SimpleEigenDecomposition SimpleEigenDecomposition(double [][] rates)
{

    // inside the main function replace this for your implementation of inverse
    DoubleMatrix Vinverse = Solve.pinv(V);
}
```

Lease squares **pinv** gives the same output as actual inverse when the matrix in invertible.

Answer (score 3):

The inverse of a matrix **A** can be found by solving **AX** = **I** where **I** is the identity matrix, and **X** will be the inverse of **A**. So, using jblas we can say

```
DoubleMatrix Vinverse = Solve.solve(A, DoubleMatrix.eye(A.rows));
```

Note that we can not invert a non-square matrix. We can check that matrix **A** is square using the [isSquare](http://jblas.org/javadoc/org/jblas/DoubleMatrix.html#isSquare--) method:

```
A.isSquare(); // returns true if it is
```